# JSP Javabean generating Error

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I have a Code like below with Variable Name and Javabean for the Variable

```
package Model;

public class SampleServ 
{
    private String Name;

    public String getName() 
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) 
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

I Created a JSP File and Used Javabean to set Value as Below

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="Model.SampleServ" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:useBean id="objUsers" class="Model.SampleServ"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:setProperty property="Name" name="objUsers" value="Mugil"/>
<jsp:getProperty property="Name" name="objUsers"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the Page displays the following Message as Below

```
Feb 12, 2013 12:32:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/JSTL] threw exception [Cannot find any information on property 'Name' in a bean of type 'Model.SampleServ'] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Cannot find any information on property 'Name' in a bean of type 'Model.SampleServ'
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.getReadMethod(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:797)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1062)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$GetProperty.accept(Node.java:1126)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:475)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3474)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:249)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:372)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:352)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:339)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:594)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:344)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
c
```

why this Happens.

Thanks for the Reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to read the `printStackTrace` message, it is cleanly showing that `Cannot find any information on property 'propertyName' in a bean of type 'Model.SampleServ'`

In this line `<jsp:setProperty property="propertyName" name="objUsers" value="Mugil"/>`
you have used **property**="`propertyName`" this should be your property name which is available inside **SampleServ** so use `property=¨Name¨`and also try to follow the **naming convention of bean properties**

**Edited**:

**SampleServ.java**

```
public class SampleServ 
{
    private String name;

    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) 
    {
       name = name;
    }
}
```

In your jsp page replace `<jsp:setProperty property="propertyName" name="objUsers" value="Mugil"/>`
with

```
<jsp:setProperty property="name" name="objUsers" value="Mugil"/>
```

Comment: When I changed it displays ClassNotFoundException

Comment: @user1973669, whic class not found put full stacktrace message.try to provide property `name` then generate the `setter getter of name`, put name in your jsp page.

Comment: Feb 12, 2013 12:32:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/JSTL] threw exception [Cannot find any information on property 'Name' in a bean of type 'Model.SampleServ'] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Cannot find any information on property 'Name' in a bean of type 'Model.SampleServ'

Comment: It works Great I don't Understand In SampleServ Class in the code i work I have given Name in Caps but in the Javabean we have used lowercase.How this works

Answer (score 1):

Your property's name is "name", not "propertyName"

Incidentally, you are not folloing standard java naming conventions. Fields should be defined with camelCase, and should be private.
i.e. `private String name;` rather than `public String Name;`

Comment: Its Displaying ClassNotFoundExeption when I do that

Comment: Thank you fro Reply Thanks a Lot